# Wordpress Permalink Redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, structure, permalinks

On the google search console i have thousands of 404 error with permalink structured like this

http://www.example.com/2016/01/11/victory-for-wenger-as-arsenal-top-premier-league-money-table/meky2xs@gmail.com

and my current permalink structure is

http://www.example.com/2016/01/victory-for-wenger-as-arsenal-top-premier-league-money-table

how do i redirect all thousand of links to this new structure via .htaccess?

and also links like `http://www.example.com/2016/07/explosion-rocks-german-immigr‌​ation-centre-nurembe‌​rg/@authorname` to this link `http://www.example.com/2016/07/explosion-rocks-german-immigr‌​ation-centre-nurembe‌​rg` in htaccess? just removing the author's name and any other link after the postname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d\d\d\d)/(\d\d)/\d\d/([^/]+) /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

That says:

Redirect xxxx/yy/zz/whatever/foo@bar to /xxxx/yy/whatever

The 'whatever' is matched up until the first slash that is encountered, and whatever's after that is discarded.

I'm further assuming that you want to REDIRECT, so that the search engines pick up on the new URL structure. If you want it to be transparent, replace the `[R=301,L]` with `[PT,L]`

Comment: how do i also tell it to redirect

Comment: how do i also tell it to redirect `http://www.example.com/2016/07/explosion-rocks-german-immigration-centre-nuremberg/@tobibowale` to this link `http://www.example.com/2016/07/explosion-rocks-german-immigration-centre-nuremberg/@authorname` in htaccess? just removing the author's name and any other link after the postname?

Comment: how about if i want to redirect this `http://www.example.com/year/month/postname/@author` to `http://www.example.com/year/month/postname` ??

Comment: This might do it:   RewriteRule ^(\d\d\d\d)/(\d\d)/([^/]+)/@.+$ /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]

Comment: This worked again...thanks

How about if i want to remove tag from the link...
`www.example.com/postname/tag` to `www.example.com/year/month/postname` ??

Comment: You might need to do that within Wordpress itself. mod_rewrite can only work with the information you give it. It can't figure out the year and month from the postname. You *could* try RewriteMap with a db lookup, but it's almost certainly not the right way to go about it.

Comment: how about removing anything after the postname/ ??

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Redirect 301 /http://www.example.com/2016/01/11/victory-for-wenger-as-arsenal-top-premier-league-money-table/meky2xs@gmail.com http://www.example.com/2016/01/victory-for-wenger-as-arsenal-top-premier-league-money-table
```

Comment: do i have to start doing it manually for the thousands of broken links?

Comment: can i try `Redirect 301 /http://www.example.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/%author%/    http://www.example.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`